# Easily access an array based on its dimensions

Tags: arrays, actionscript, syntax, multidimensional-array, eval

Lets say I have an array which has *n* dimensions. Now in order to access a slot you typically use:

```
 array [1][0]
```

What if the number of dimensions are not known at compile-time, is there an easy access like:

```
 slot = "1,0"
 array [slot]   // accessing 1,0
```

Which means I can also easily navigate back and forth

```
 slot += ",2"
 array [slot]   // accessing 1,0,2
```

Any such way to access any slot in a multidim array in one line of code, in ActionScript? I'm not looking for alternative code, that does it indirectly, (recursive functions or loops).

In JavaScript you could:

```
 slot = "1,0"
 eval("array[" + slot + "]")    // accessing 1,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such facility in AS3. Neither is `eval` (taken out due to security reasons mostly, IIRC). The latter also being one of those few areas where AS3 differs from the ECMAScript specification.

Comment: How about AS2? Would ActionScript 2 support any such feature?

Comment: Haven't used AS2. There is an eval() -- you can give it a try.

Comment: Honestly, I don't get your point. Are you saying that the only acceptable answer is what you would like it to be?

Comment: i.e. I'd wouldn't like to conclusively accept defeat, in that the platform supports no such feature. That would be a pity.